# How to download and save file from BLOB response of an Api in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, blob

I am working on a Flutter app and integrated REST Apis to parse the JSON response but one of the Api giving me BLOB response.

Here is the some portion of the BLOB response you can see:

> << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 12635 >> stream
> x��}ےGr�;�"�$��f@#�����R�qhwe�l��]j���&���O�8~�,4@s4&��̌p?~��#2�;�.�?o^?����sn���uח��߇Ż���x�,���ovo����sy�/��^��)}�����3'�|s�����������Ͳ��X������c7i�̏�����������웏]T�����E>����ay~���9߽ڝ/�����.�!ܽ�{��c?O}�-����ۋ���~�v�9�x�����̧t���B�'���|�����%r�����Ü�W��^��|�[����/z��9��G)�^�R�G�/��b���Y�}�<U�T�D��C�g-'�k'9���?���B�"�"�ѰΪ�;��I�)��B��zs�+�%�{�$�������V��/}��R"��Dr�g������;i��m�+��[i$��I��+�YG+�&Q+��"�̖�WBv�����c\�_9�Frz��r��b��Д:Z1d����d}����Bv�.���h�\��c��B&��c�iÐڰ\әo�9���4^�|�y4cr�;����ޙ�s0��9��<c����N̵�9q"�9ľ�4i�d

The Api is related to File download functionality and the above response is just a file I need to open from application. It is a file in short.

How can I download and save file from this BLOB response in Flutter app?

Comment: Have you tried converting the Blob response using [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64Decode.html)?

Comment: not getting much idea about it, can you please explain it?

Comment: ```base64.decode(blob);``` from dart:convert